# Asp.net 4.8 WebForms authorization using Owin OpenId Connect Authentication (app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication)

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure-active-directory, owin

I am encountering an infinite redirect loop between login.microsoftonline.com and my application. My project is implementing authentication and authorization in an Asp.net 4.8 web forms project. I am able to add authentication using the default Owin startup file and then require authentication in the web config file. The below works correctly for requiring a user to sign in before being able to access `pages/AuthRequired`

StartupAuth.CS

```cs
public partial class Startup
    {
        private static string clientId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:ClientId"];
        private static string postLogoutRedirectUri = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:PostLogoutRedirectUri"];
        private static string authority = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:Authority"];
        private static string clientSecret = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AppRegistrationSecret-Local"];
        public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            //for debugging
            //IdentityModelEventSource.ShowPII = true;

            app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

            app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());
            app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
                new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
                {
                    ClientId = clientId,
                    Authority = authority,
                    PostLogoutRedirectUri = postLogoutRedirectUri,
                    ClientSecret = clientSecret,
                    RedirectUri = postLogoutRedirectUri,
                    //This allows multitenant
                    //https://github.com/Azure-Samples/guidance-identity-management-for-multitenant-apps/blob/master/docs/03-authentication.md
                    TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                    {
                        ValidateIssuer = false
                    },

                    Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications()
                    {
                        AuthenticationFailed = (context) =>
                        {
                            return Task.FromResult(0);
                        }
                    }
                }
                );

            // This makes any middleware defined above this line run before the Authorization rule is applied in web.config
            app.UseStageMarker(PipelineStage.Authenticate);
        }
    }
```

Web.Config

```xml
<configuration>
...
    <system.web>
        <authentication mode="None" />
    </system.web>
    <location path="Pages/AuthRequired">
        <system.web>
            <authorization>
                <deny users="?" />
            </authorization>
        </system.web>
    </location>
    <system.webServer>
        <modules>
            <remove name="FormsAuthentication" />
        </modules>
    </system.webServer>
...
</configuration>
```

I need to add authorization so that only users with the admin role will be able to access `Pages/AuthRequired`. I have done that by updating the web config:

```xml
<configuration>
...
    <system.web>
        <authentication mode="None" />
    </system.web>
    <location path="Pages/AuthRequired">
        <system.web>
            <authorization>
                <allow roles="Admin" />
                <deny users="*" />
            </authorization>
        </system.web>
    </location>
    <system.webServer>
        <modules>
            <remove name="FormsAuthentication" />
        </modules>
    </system.webServer>
...
</configuration>
```

Adding authorization to the authenticated page works correctly if the user has that role, but if a user who doesn't have the role tries to access the page they are redirected back to login.microsoftonline.com and then back to the application in an infinite loop.

I can see that Owin UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication is returning a 302 response on unauthorized and that is causing the loop.

How can I change it so that instead of redirecting unauthorized (but authenticated) users to login.microsoftonline.com, that user should be directed to an app page that displays a 401 error?

Answer (score 0):

Please check if below work around helps:

Its usually possible that if `forms authentication` is enabled, you will  be redirected to the login page when status code is 401.

As a workaround try Adding the below to global.asax in the application end request and you can create own unauthorized page if needed and redirect to that.

```
if (this.Response.StatusCode == 302&& this.Response.StatusCode == 401 
        && this.Response.RedirectLocation.ToLower().Contains("login.aspx"))
      {
        this.Response.StatusCode = 401;
         //or Response.Redirect("Unauthorized.aspx");
      }
```

You can also check this > [Redirect unauthorised user to message page in ASP .Net. (microsoft.com)](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/14774cc6-2f3d-4ae4-8c61-9d3a2808f728/redirect-unauthorised-user-to-message-page-in-asp-net)

**Other references**

1. [Prevent redirect to login on status code 401 (Unauthorized)
   (microsoft.com)](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/vstudio/en-US/b6b0cd09-a95a-483e-8ad3-48a90d66d11c/prevent-redirect-to-login-on-status-code-401-unauthorized)
2. [asp.net - In-place handling (no redirect) of 401 unauthorized? -
   Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20576697/in-place-handling-no-redirect-of-401-unauthorized)

Comment: Thanks, @kavyasaraboju-MT, I am actually not using forms authentication, I am using the OWIN middleware instead. I will update the web.config snippet above to make that clear

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET URL Authorization doesn't appear to interoperate well with OIDC (i.e. Azure AD).

First remove the URL Authorization from your Web.config:

```
<configuration>
...
    <system.web>
        <authentication mode="None" />
    </system.web>
    <location path="Pages/AuthRequired">
        <system.web>
--            <authorization>
--                <allow roles="Admin" />
--                <deny users="*" />
--            </authorization>
        </system.web>
    </location>
    <system.webServer>
        <modules>
            <remove name="FormsAuthentication" />
        </modules>
    </system.webServer>
...
</configuration>
```

Optionally make authenticated required for all pages globally:

```xml
    <system.web>
      <deny users="?" />
    </system.web>
```

You can override this behaviour with `<Allow users="?" />` for specific pages i.e. logins/logouts/erorr pages/etc.

Second add authorization logic to your `AuthRequired.aspx` page:

```cs
public partial class AuthRequired {
  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    Authorization.AuthorizeAuthRequiredPage();
    ...
  }
}

public static class Authorization
{
  public static void AuthorizeAuthRequiredPage()
  {
    if (!Authorized(HttpContext.User))
    {
      Redirect("/Anauthorized.aspx");
    }
  }

  private static bool Authorized(User user) => { ... }
}
```